# Error in MouseRNAseqData() ( scRNA seq analysis)

Tags: rna-seq

I've installed [celldex](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/experiment/html/celldex.html) from bioconductor, and I got this error message!

Could anyone help me in solving this problem please?

```
ref <- MouseRNAseqData()
Error in `collect()`:
! Failed to collect lazy table.
Caused by error in `db_collect()`:
! Arguments in `...` must be used.
✖ Problematic argument:
• ..1 = Inf
ℹ Did you misspell an argument name?
```

I have installed this:

```r
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("celldex")
```